# How to find X and Y of clustered features?

Tags: openlayers-2

How can I find longitude latitude values of clustered features?

Please look the image. I hope you understand my question. I need to find out the X and Y of clustered features on every zoom levels.

[image]

Sample Code:

```
var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeColor     : "#FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity   : 1,
        strokeWidth     : 2,
        fillColor       : settings.color,
        fillOpacity     : 0.9,
        cursor          : "pointer",
        pointRadius     : "${point_radius}",
        pointerEvents   : "visiblePainted",
        label           : "${label}",
        fontColor       : "#000000",
        fontSize        : "12px",
        fontFamily      : "verdana",
        fontWeight      : "bold",
        labelAlign      : "center" 
    }, {
        context: {
            label: function(feature) {
                var sumValue = 0;
                if(feature.attributes.count>1) {
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) {
                        sumValue++;
                    }
                    return sumValue;
                }else{
                    return 1;
                }
            },
            point_radius: function(feature) {
                var pix = 10;
                if(feature.cluster) {
                    pix =Math.min(feature.attributes.count, 30) * 2.5 + 8;
                }
                return pix;
            }
        }
    });

    var onSelectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeColor     : "#000000",
        fontColor       : "#FFFFFF",
        pointerEvents   : "visiblePainted",
        fontSize        : "15px"
    });

    var strategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance: 30, threshold: 2});

    var ly=new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(GSMapLayerName,{
            strategies: [strategy],
            styleMap:new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default":defaultStyle,
                        "select": onSelectStyle
                    }),
            displayInLayerSwitcher:false
        });
    map.addLayer(ly);
```

Note: I am using openlayers 2.11

Thanks for any reply

Comment: You can access the coordinates at layer.features[i].geometry

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you explain little bit more.. I think you are asking me to do like this `var fts=map.getLayersByName(GSMapLayerName).feature; for(var i=0;i<fts.length;i++){ var x=features[i].geometry.x; }` is it right?

Comment: Yes, you can access the values in that way and use them. What do you need them for?

Comment: I am trying to show heat map using features count.Actually, I downloaded heatmap from [http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/index.html] and tried to add "heatmap-openlayers-renderer" method.But its not working. Because I am using openlayers 2.11. So I am trying this way... :)